# onChange not working as intended without callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, formik, setstate

this snippet of code gives me a bad setState error. I want the code in onChange to run immediately without a callback ()=> after onChange, as I want a button to disable if all the form fields are not filled out. If I use a callback, onChange is always one change behind. Is there a way around this?

```html
          <FormControl
            onChange={
              Object.keys(formik.errors).length === 0 &&
              Object.keys(formik.touched).length >= 2
                ? setErrorState(false, formik.values)
                : setErrorState(true)
            }
          >
```

Here is the full code

```html
import {
  Box,
  FormControl,
  Flex,
  Heading,
  VStack,
  Stack,
  Text,
  Radio,
  RadioGroup,
  Tooltip,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import TextField from "./TextField";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setExpress } from "../redux/actions/cartActions";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  setShippingAddress,
  setShippingAddressError,
} from "../redux/actions/orderActions";

const ShippingInformation = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //formik
  const [formStateChanged, setFormStateChanged] = useState(false);

  // function
  const setErrorState = (errorState, data) => {
    //dispatches shipping info if the user has filled in all field with at least two characters (errorState === false),
    if (errorState === false) {
      dispatch(setShippingAddress(data));
    }
    if (
      (!formStateChanged && !errorState) ||
      (formStateChanged && errorState)
    ) {
      return;
    } else {
      setFormStateChanged(errorState);
      dispatch(setShippingAddressError(errorState));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ address: "", postalCode: "", city: "", country: "" }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        address: Yup.string()
          .required("This field is required.")
          .min(2, "This address is too short."),
        postalCode: Yup.string()
          .required("This field is required.")
          .min(2, "This postal code is too short."),
        city: Yup.string()
          .required("This field is required.")
          .min(2, "This city name is is too short."),
        country: Yup.string()
          .required("This field is required.")
          .min(2, "This country name is too short."),
      })}
    >
      {(formik) => (
        <VStack as="form">
          <FormControl
            onChange={
              Object.keys(formik.errors).length === 0 &&
              Object.keys(formik.touched).length >= 2
                ? setErrorState(false, formik.values)
                : setErrorState(true)
            }
          >
            <TextField
              name="address"
              placeholder="Street Address"
              label="Street Address"
            />
            <Flex>
              <Box flex="1" mr="10">
                <TextField
                  name="postalCode"
                  placeholder="Postal Code"
                  label="Postal Code"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box flex="2">
                <TextField name="city" placeholder="City" label="City" />
              </Box>
            </Flex>
            <TextField name="country" placeholder="Country" label="Country" />
          </FormControl>
          <Box width="100%" height="180px" pr="5px">
            <Heading fontSize="2xl" fontWeight="extrabold" mb="10px">
              Shipping Method
            </Heading>
            <RadioGroup
              defaultValue="false"
              onChange={(event) => {
                dispatch(setExpress(event));
              }}
            >
              <Stack
                direction={{ base: "column", lg: "row" }}
                align={{ lg: "flex-start" }}
              >
                <Stack pr="10" spacing={{ base: "8px", md: "10px" }} flex="1.5">
                  <Box>
                    <Radio value="true">
                      <Text fontWeight="bold">Express Shipping $14.99</Text>
                      <Text>Shipped within 24 hours</Text>
                    </Radio>
                  </Box>
                  <Stack spacing="6px">
                    <Text>Express</Text>
                  </Stack>
                </Stack>
                <Radio value="false">
                  <Tooltip label="Free shipping for all orders over $1,000.">
                    <Box>
                      <Text fontWeight="bold">Standard Shipping $4.99</Text>
                      <Text>Shipped within two to three business days</Text>
                    </Box>
                  </Tooltip>
                </Radio>
              </Stack>
            </RadioGroup>
          </Box>
        </VStack>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default ShippingInformation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s because you need to wrap it in a function, otherwise it executes immediately.

Comment: I tried separating it into a separate handlefunction but it still gives the same result unless I have a callback

Comment: Make sure you write it as `onChange={() => handleFunction()}` (or `onChange={handleFunction}`), and _not_ `onChange={handleFunction()}` else you get this exacty situation again.

Comment: Yes I did both those methods. No dice.

Answer (score 0):

handleFunction() worked thanks!